# Is there any way to install Musicbee on Ubuntu

Tags: wine, 17.10, media, music-player

https://getmusicbee.com

It's my favorite music player/manager. I tried a lot but can't seem to able to make it work on Ubuntu using Wine. I use Ubuntu 17.10 and wine-2.0.2.

I downloaded the .exe installer and used wine to install it. I had to change the windows version to windows 7 in winecfg and then installed dotnet4. 
[The program seems to have been installed,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6tPFb.png) but doesn't open.

[I have attached the terminal output.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RtrK4.png)

Thanks

Comment: So, what did you try and how did it fail ? Please update your question with relevant (some - any) information.

Comment: The terminal output ('unimplemented function') makes it pretty clear that you are wasting your time. It won't work. Time to learn a new favorite music player. Remember to clean up your failed experiment.

Comment: Ok then. I suppose I will have to do with clementine.